# How to decide the rank of N horses with M tracks?

Tags: algorithm

Providing N horses and M(M <= N) tracks but no timer, all you could get from one round is the order of M horses. The questions how many rounds at least, if you want to get the rank of all horses?

e.g.
`N=3, M=3, Round=1;
N=3, M=2, Round=3;
N=4, M=3, Round=3;`

what is Round, when N=1000, M=3?

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: Interesting... a sort algorithm for ternary logic.

Comment: It's a question I've meet in a interview, I could not get a precise result, but only a upper bound, using merge-sort.

Comment: @Ed: Ternary logic would mean that, for every pair of horses, you have three different possible outcomes (for example, "A wins", "B wins", and "too close to call"). What we have here is a slightly different setting (a triple of horses and 3!=6 possible outcomes per round).

Comment: which company? and it would help if you post your upper bound here.

Comment: I've found a paper proposed last year. http://www.math.illinois.edu/REGS/reports10/HanKimMc10.pdf

Comment: @Martin - sorry, right you are.  So I guess that would make it sexary, or maybe just sexy?

Comment: @Ed: Take your pick... ;) (The "real" name for this, according to Wikipedia, seems to be "senary": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senary)

Answer (score 4):

You can get a lower bound with information theory.

Each race gives you log(m!) bits of information, and you need log(n!) bits.  So a natural lowerbound on the number of races is then log(n!) / log(m!).

Answer (score 0):

Formal definition of the problem -

http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~west/regs/ksetsort.html